# Why is it possible to animate in browser if delay_num of apng file is 0 on web?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web, browser, apng

If the value corresponding to delayN is 0 in the apng information, I wonder why it is animated normally in the browser

delayN information was referring to js lib (https://github.com/davidmz/apng-js/blob/master/src/library/parser.js#L62)).

The apng-js lib corrects frame.delay to 100, but does the browser do the same?
(https://github.com/davidmz/apng-js/blob/master/src/library/parser.js#L71)
If delayN(delay_num) is 0, shouldn't it not work in browser(chrome)?

I want to know how to handle it in the browser(chrome)

Ref.

- https://www.w3.org/TR/png/#fcTL-chunk - delay_num

---

if the duration of apng is 0, then a crash occurred on the android app. So I was curious about the reason why it is animated normally in the browser.

Comment: The specs you linked to says "If the the value of the numerator is 0 the decoder should render the next frame as quickly as possible, though viewers may impose a reasonable lower bound." Why would you expect it to not animate? Or are you wondering only about what's the delay in the current Chromium implementation?

Comment: As a result, if the duration of apng is 0, then a crash occurred on the android app. So I was curious about the reason why it is animated normally in the browser.